# Multiple Skype Accounts in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, skype

We use Skype at work and I use Skype at home, however I have two accounts so clients can't call me at home and I'm not distracted when I'm at work.

I've just upgraded my laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 8, in 7 I'd sign into one then sign out.  With Windows 8 you have to tie it to your Windows Account.

How can I maintain this distinction and still use my laptop for Skype calls when I work at home?

Comment: You may have to create two Windows Accounts. I'm not sure if that's possible though (I haven't checked the T&C's)

Comment: @ChrisF my backup is a local useraccount for my box but I really don't want to have to do that for the sake of Skype...

Comment: I figured that which is why I didn't suggest it as an answer...

Comment: Use the desktop skype application.  The Modern UI Application is limited to a single account from my understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the 2nd account on Desktop Skype. Your Microsoft account in <strike>Metro</strike> Modern Skype.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, all are valid however I'm selecting this one as it's simplest and doesn't require two Microsoft accounts.

Answer (score 3):

I use two separate Windows logon accounts. One for work with my work Skype, one for home with my home Skype. I also separate the work and home email this way in Outlook too. Documents, pics, vids and audio I want to share go in the public folders, which I just include in the libraries on both accounts. My work account is set up as an admin user, the home account is a normal user, but you can make them both admin users if you want. 
HTH

Answer (score 2):

These are some of the things i got while goggling and i am sharing it with you.

get to windows 8 screen type in Run

and follow these steps.

In the Run window, enter the following command (include the quotes) and press OK:

"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary 
another solution is also there i am just providing you the Link

https://support.skype.com/en/category/VIDEO/

Hope this Helps..

Answer (score 0):

Modern Skype supports login only with the Microsoft account. But, you can use Skype desktop client instead of modern Skype: http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-full

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one more point over here.Usually we can link only one skype account to our microsoft account.So when you wants to use skype account at office.Then you can linked to your official account by login to skype account and put your outlook credentials over there and in case at home.You can merge your home account to your micorsoft account.So right now this is the only way two handled different skype account in a windows 8 and skype in windows devices.Please revert me in case of any confusion.