# Multiple account Skype for business / Lync

Tags: skype

How to login with more than one account on SfB (Lync) pls  ?
Or how to open more than one instance of SfB / Lync ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Skype Accounts in Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/497549/multiple-skype-accounts-in-windows-8)

Comment: @moutonjr I am aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have done this is running the Outlook Office 365 web interface. That allows you to get skype pings for that domain. Lync (Skype for business) currently does not allow multiple accounts via a single interface (like a calendar merge in Outlook). Skype personal is the only program that has the ability to spawn a secondary desktop session.